# Rails Tutorial 4.1 Bootstrap CCS not rendering properly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm on part 5 of the [Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout) and I'm having an issue with the Bootstrap CSS. I just included it and the navbar isn't rendering as expected. This is what's happening:

[image]

As you can see the navbar items aren't horizontal but vertical. This is the HTML markup right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue? I don't have any extraneous CSS added yet.

Comment: You haven't shown us the CSS. How are we supposed to fix it?

Comment: It's the default Bootstrap CSS, I haven't changed anything.

Comment: When you view the source of the page, is the CSS file included?

Comment: Yep, the only line in my CSS file is @import "bootstrap";

Comment: hey, which version of bootstrap are you using? did you add all the bootstrap css files and js files to the respective assets folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems it was an issue with my version of Bootstrap and the version the tutorial uses. To fix the issue I just changed this line:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
```

To this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

And got the desired result:

[image]